# Do I need to AddRef() if returning pointer to pointer COM object from function?

Tags: c++, winapi, com

Below is a function that loads resource image from executable into `ID2D1Bitmap` pointer.

My question is, do I need to call `AddRef()` on `ID2D1Bitmap** ppBitmap` function parameter?

for example at the end of the function do I need this:

```
(*ppBitmap)->AddRef();
```

I see code around internet do such call sometimes, sometimes not but I'm unable to understand when this is valid and when not?

Note: For minimum compilable code I provide whole function, excluding error checking implementation.

```
#include <sdkddkver.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <wincodec.h>   // WIC
#include <d2d1.h>       // ID2D1Bitmap

//
// Loads resource Image from executable
// into ID2D1Bitmap* pointer
//
template<typename RenderType>
HRESULT LoadResourceImage(
    IWICImagingFactory* pFactory,
    PCTSTR szFilename,
    PCTSTR szFileType,
    RenderType* pRenderTarget,
    ID2D1Bitmap** ppBitmap)
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    DWORD dwImageSize = 0;
    HMODULE hModule = GetModuleHandle(nullptr);

    HRSRC hResource = nullptr;
    HGLOBAL hResourceData = nullptr;
    void* pImageFile = nullptr;
    IWICStream* pStream = nullptr;
    IWICFormatConverter* pConverter = nullptr;
    IWICBitmapFrameDecode* pFrameDecode = nullptr;
    IWICBitmapDecoder* pDecoder = nullptr;

    if (!hModule)
    {
        ShowError(__FILENAME__, __LINE__);
        goto done;
    }

    hResource = FindResource(hModule, szFilename, szFileType);
    if (!hResource)
    {
        ShowError(__FILENAME__, __LINE__);
        goto done;
    }

    if (FAILED(hr = hResource ? S_OK : E_FAIL))
    {
        ShowError(__FILENAME__, __LINE__, hr);
        goto done;
    }

    dwImageSize = SizeofResource(hModule, hResource);
    if (!dwImageSize)
    {
        ShowError(__FILENAME__, __LINE__);
        goto done;
    }

    if (FAILED(hr = dwImageSize ? S_OK : E_FAIL))
    {
        ShowError(__FILENAME__, __LINE__, hr);
        goto done;
    }

    hResourceData = LoadResource(hModule, hResource);
    if (!hResourceData)
    {
        ShowError(__FILENAME__, __LINE__);
        goto done;
    }

    if (FAILED(hr = hResourceData ? S_OK : E_FAIL))
    {
        ShowError(__FILENAME__, __LINE__, hr);
        goto done;
    }

    pImageFile = LockResource(hResourceData);
    if (!pImageFile)
    {
        ShowError(__FILENAME__, __LINE__);
        goto done;
    }

    if (FAILED(hr = pImageFile ? S_OK : E_FAIL))
    {
        ShowError(__FILENAME__, __LINE__, hr);
        goto done;
    }

    if (FAILED(hr = pFactory->CreateStream(&pStream)))
    {
        ShowError(__FILENAME__, __LINE__, hr);
        goto done;
    }

    hr = pStream->InitializeFromMemory(
        reinterpret_cast<BYTE*>(pImageFile), dwImageSize);

    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        ShowError(__FILENAME__, __LINE__, hr);
        goto done;
    }

    hr = pFactory->CreateDecoderFromStream(
        pStream,
        nullptr,
        WICDecodeMetadataCacheOnDemand,
        &pDecoder);

    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        ShowError(__FILENAME__, __LINE__, hr);
        goto done;
    }

    if (FAILED(hr = pDecoder->GetFrame(0, &pFrameDecode)))
    {
        ShowError(__FILENAME__, __LINE__, hr);
        goto done;
    }

    if (FAILED(hr = pFactory->CreateFormatConverter(&pConverter)))
    {
        ShowError(__FILENAME__, __LINE__, hr);
        goto done;
    }

    hr = pConverter->Initialize(
        pFrameDecode,
        GUID_WICPixelFormat32bppPRGBA,
        WICBitmapDitherTypeNone,
        nullptr,
        0.f,
        WICBitmapPaletteTypeCustom);

    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        ShowError(__FILENAME__, __LINE__, hr);
        goto done;
    }

    hr = pRenderTarget->CreateBitmapFromWicBitmap(
        pConverter,
        0,
        ppBitmap);

    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        ShowError(__FILENAME__, __LINE__, hr);
        goto done;
    }

done:
    SafeRelease(&pFrameDecode);
    SafeRelease(&pDecoder);
    SafeRelease(&pConverter);
    SafeRelease(&pStream);

    return hr;
}
```

Comment: no, you not need do this. you simply finally return result of `CreateBitmapFromWicBitmap`

Comment: No, CreateBitmapFromWicBitmap() already did that.  So a single Release() call in the code that uses your function is enough to destroy it again.

Comment: Do you know in which case do I need to `AddRef()` ? any rules regarding AddRef

Comment: in general [Rules for Managing Reference Counts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/com/rules-for-managing-reference-counts) but you need understand referece counting yourself. also [Managing the Lifetime of an Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/learnwin32/managing-the-lifetime-of-an-object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> hr = pRenderTarget->CreateBitmapFromWicBitmap(
>         pConverter,
>         0,
>         ppBitmap);
> ```

The `ID2D1Bitmap` object returned by successful calls of the `CreateBitmapFromWicBitmap` method above, *already* has a proper reference count set. So, you *shouldn't* call `AddRef` on it.

You only need to invoke `Release` on the `ID2D1Bitmap*` COM interface pointer when you're done with the object.

On the contrary, if you explicitly invoke `AddRef` one more time on the returned pointer, you will need a proper *additional* matching `Release` call, or the returned object won't free itself.

Note that, since we are discussing C++ code (not C code), you can *simplify* all this COM interface pointer life-cycle management code using *smart* pointers like [`ATL::CComPtr`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl/reference/ccomptr-class), instead of raw pointers to COM interfaces.

`CComPtr` will *automatically* invoke `AddRef` and `Release` on the wrapped raw COM interface pointers (for example, at the end of scope, `Release` will be invoked by the `~CComPtr` destructor), so you don't have to pay attention to these COM object life-time details. Moreover, also in case of exceptions, `Release` will be invoked automatically as well, so you won't leak COM objects when exceptions are thrown.